# New iptables NAT produces Error 400 Bad Request for Other HTTP Requests

Tags: iptables, openvpn, http, nat

All:

Recently, I added several new iptables (RE: code snippet below) rules to route traffic through my VPN (0x1000/0x1000) for a specific destination (172.67.168.48) over port 443. The new rules NAT over the VPN as desired, but they've created an undesired effect causing other HTTP requests, unrelated to the aforementioned destination, to produce an error response 400 Bad Request.

```
# Create the RPDB rules
ip rule add from 0/0 fwmark "0x1000/0x1000" table ovpnc1 prio 9993        # VPN 1 fwmark

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -d 172.67.168.48 --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1000/0x1000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x1000/0x1000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.67.168.48:443
```

Any idea why other HTTP requests would be affected (400 Bad Request) by the new NAT rules when the destination address and port are clearly specified?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Kind Regards,

Gary

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here? This looks completely unnecessary. It looks like you are doing a DNAT instead of the expected routing.

Comment: The goal is to mark the specified destination packets for traversal of the VPN (oppose to the WAN).  The iptables rules work, they just break other HTTP requests (400 Error) on the VPN. It sounds like you're suggesting there is more than one way to implement this task?

Comment: But why did you DNAT? You're supposed to route.

Comment: It has been quite some time since I've developed iptables rules and the examples I found on this site suggested DNAT was the way to implement it. I'm open to alternate iptables routing, if you'd like to provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All:

It turns out my original iptables -t nat rule was missing the --dport 443 definition and the reason why it was interacting with Other HTTP requests.

```
# Create the RPDB rules
ip rule add from 0/0 fwmark "0x1000/0x1000" table ovpnc1 prio 9993        # VPN 1 fwmark

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 172.67.168.48 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2000/0x2000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.67.168.48:443 -m mark --mark 0x2000/0x2000
```

Once the --dport 443 definition was added to the iptables -t nat rule the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Respectfully,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

**VPN Server:** Assuming **eth0** (IP `1.2.3.4`) is the physical interface that is directly attached to or at least has the route to the target web-server's IP or network, you can monitor any traffic destined to the web-server IP `172.67.168.48:443`, to be forced through the VPN tunnel and then NATted out to eth0's IP address (`1.2.3.4` in this example). In this case, **br0** interface (IP `10.10.10.1`) is the virtual interface that the VPN server is using to tunnel the traffic. While the VPN is up and running, it already knows how to route packets to destination IP `172.67.168.48`

If not, then you have to add a static route:

```
$ ip route show
172.67.168.48/32 via 10.10.10.1 dev br0 metric 101
```

Once the route statement is satisfied, then you can force traffic destined to IP `172.67.168.48:443` to be routed through the tunnel and exit on the other side as `1.2.3.4` en-route `172.67.168.48`

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 172.67.168.48 --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

If a client sends a packet to `172.67.168.48:80` for example, the source IP will not change, and the packet may be discarded if not allowed by subsequent chains.